# assigning values to js variable on the server from the client

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, cookies

I have an object that is SERVER sided, as in it's in a .js file that the client won't have direct access to:

```
var Stuffs= {
'a':{
    '1':{
        'I':'someSTRING',
        'II':'someSTRING',
        'III':someBOOLEAN,
        'IV':[
            ['IVa','someSTRING'],
            ['IVb',someINTEGER],
            ['IVc',someINTEGER],],
        'V':{
            'Va':someINTEGER,
            'Vb':someINTEGER},
        'VI':someINTEGER},
    '2':{
        'I':'someSTRING',
        'II':'someSTRING',
        'III':someBOOLEAN,
        'IV':[
            ['IVa','someSTRING'],
            ['IVb',someINTEGER],],
        'V':{
            'Va':someINTEGER,
            'Vb':someINTEGER},
        'VI':someINTEGER},
},
'b':{},
'c':{}};
function saveII(Stuff_to_save){
    Stuffs['a']['1']['II'] = Stuff_to_save;
    //This code works until the page is refreshed.
}
```

I have made it so the client can mess around and change the II values, but now I need a way to push that back up to the server.
I'm thinking along the lines of send it to my php, which can rewrite the js file, but that seems like an excessive waste of time.
or maybe using cookies, though I have NO experience in that.
Note: Clients can save the variable, and load it, but on a page refresh it gets wiped.

Comment: I am a bit confused do you want the client to be able to change the file on the server or not? If not they why would you push it to the server, if so why would the changes be wiped on refresh?

Comment: @aduss I ONLY want people to have access to that one piece of my object, I figured make it have to go through something else like ajax or php first made it easier

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. So unfortunately if you access that file via client side JavaScript directly the user will be able to see the entire thing. That being said all changes made would only be only avaliable for that session and only to that user. You would have to write a PHP or Node or some other server side script that only returns the part of the file you want people to see.

Comment: @aduss Yes, that's the second half of my post, but I don't know how

Comment: I am not terribly familiar with PHP but I would create a PHP file/server function that returns MIME type JSON and then use something like json_decode to grab out the part I wanted. I will leave others to answer this now.